# Calling List<T>.Clear() causing IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have a `List<T>` that is in an entity class that is being populated via NHibernate. When I call `.Clear()` on that list, I am getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

I've verified that that list has items in in before this is called, but the same exception is thrown.

Under what circumstances would you expect to get this exception when you call this method?

```
private readonly List<VacancyTag> _vacancyTags = new List<VacancyTag>();

public virtual void RemoveAllVacancyTags()
{
    _vacancyTags.Clear();
}
```

Edit:

The crazy thing is that even after the exception is thrown and I break the debugger, I can query the object in the immediate window and can confirm that the Count() method is returning the value 5!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429562/problem-with-clearing-a-listt in case of a multi-threading issue.

Comment: is the collection throwing the exception or NHibernate ?

Comment: It's not NHibernate throwing the exception. Looking through the Exception properties there is no mention of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A typical case is when you have multiple threads accessing the same list.

If one thread deletes an item while the list is being cleared by another thread, this exception could be thrown.

Remember the `List<T>` class is **not** thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not doing anything that is multi threaded. It's a bog standard small web app that is doing nothing fancy.

Comment: I'll implement the thread safe list, just to completely rule it out and report back! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using threads, please lock the call of the method `Clear()`.

```
private readonly object obj = new Object();

private readonly List<VacancyTag> _vacancyTags = new List<VacancyTag>();

public virtual void RemoveAllVacancyTags()
{
    lock(obj)
    {
        _vacancyTags.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Better try to use a concurrent collection s. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx